# Radio buttons ng-required checkbox like

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, ng-required

I'm having a little problem with some radio buttons inside my form. I know that a checkbox could do this in a real easy way but, you know, customer asking for this.

So, this is the form part:

```
<label>
    <span>Acconsento*</span>
    <input type="radio" name="privacy_1" value="1" ng-model="ctrl.utente.privacy_1" ng-required="!ctrl.isValidPrivacy()"/>
</label>
<label>
    <span>Non acconsento</span>
    <input type="radio" name="privacy_1" value="0" ng-model="ctrl.utente.privacy_1"/>
</label>
```

With respective JS part:

```
self.isValidPrivacy = function () {
    return (!self.utente.privacy_1 || self.utente.privacy_1 == 0) ? false : true;
};
```

and `ctrl.utente.privacy_1` must be `== 1`.

After trying `ng-required="ctrl.utente.privacy_1 != 1"`
or `ng-required="!ctrl.utente.privacy_1` (removing `value="0"` from 2nd radio input) I still haven't found a way to accomplish this.

`ctrl.utente.privacy_1 == 0` isn't shown as validation error, and it can't be selected by default (`ctrl.utente.privacy_1` can't be `false` by default)

All others answers on StackOverflow doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you have some messed concepts...

First, you don't need a ternary operator to discern between true and false, just return the result of the comparision:

```
return (!self.utente.privacy_1 || self.utente.privacy_1 == 0);
```

would be enough. That said, you don't even need a function to check for this, you could do it directly on the attribute, since it's a simple check:

```
<... ng-required="!$ctrl.utente.privacy_1 || $ctrl.utente.privacy_1 == 0" .../>
```

That said, I don't understand why do you need an ng-required at all, maybe you've missunderstood its meaning... ng-required it's used to force the user to give a value to an input field, is NOT for checking it's value, that is what it seems you're trying to do. If you want to be sure that the user selects one of the two options just use the html attribute 'required' on both inputs, and that's enough.

```
<label>
    <span>Acconsento*</span>
    <input type="radio" name="privacy_1" value="1" ng-model="ctrl.utente.privacy_1" required />
</label>
<label>
    <span>Non acconsento</span>
    <input type="radio" name="privacy_1" value="0" ng-model="ctrl.utente.privacy_1" required />
</label>
```

Comment: After my question I've actually simplified my function as you did. By the way, I had already tried your ng-required clause, but that wasn't working, because I need that value to be 1, not 0 nor false

Comment: I haven't used ng-required, only required, but just to force the user to set a value for ctrl.utente.privacy_1 model. One tip: if you are using controllerAs syntax with the default notation then 'ctrl' should be '$ctrl' and that may be causing your headaches... I'm pretty sure my answer is right!

Comment: I need that value to be 1, if I put required on each one of them, it will accept 0 as value too. Anyway I've solved just removing ng-model from the 2nd option

Comment: You keep confused... The required attribute forces that "one of the valid values" must be assigned to the field, it doesn't force any of these values to be applied to the model. If you really don't want the value 0 assigned to the model, just remove ng-model from the imputs and assign utente.privacy_1 on the controller, but as I told before, you'll end having a radio group that has no meaning, because it doesn't set anything.